# Trying to make an AND gate but it's not working in online simulation

Tags: transistors, led, circuit-design, switches, breadboard

[image]

The image above is what I'm trying to remake on a breadboard.

The image below is my attempt to remake it, but it's not working and I have no idea why.

[image]

Any help? I am pretty new to circuits.

Comment: instead of saying it doesn't work, tell us what you see it doing that is contrary to what you expect. (I am going to guess that the LED seems to be "on" when you expect it to be off. Be aware that LEDs do not need very much current to make visible light. The leakage current of your transistors might be enough to get a dim glow, even when they are "supposed to be" off. That's my first guess, but again, please tell us what you are seeing).

Comment: `leakage current` especially without base-emitter(or ground) resistors.

Comment: I only see one transistor on your breadboard, are you trying to make a one input AND gate? Also your switch doesn't appear to be connected to anything but the positive rail.

Comment: Your title says your simulation isn't working but the body of the question is about the breadboard implementation. Which is it?

Answer (score 7):

Sorry, but your breadboard layout bears no resemblance to the circuit diagram.
Only one transistor instead of two.
Only one switch instead of two.
Both legs of the LED are shorted together by being plugged into the same horizontal row of sockets.
The component values don't match the circuit diagram, but that doesn't really matter. They are close enough that the circuit *should* work if it wasn't for the other errors.
The two 10K resistors appear to be in series, one goes to the base of the transistor, and the other end goes to 0V. Nothing like the circuit.

Comment: The junction of the two 10Ks don't connect to the switch.  there is only one connection to the switch, so it won't do anything.

Comment: Looks like he also has a dead short between the legs of the LED.

Answer (score 2):

Make the wiring short and neat and use a yellow marker on a copy of the schematic after inserting each connection.  Don't use up all the space when you don't have to. Make it tight & Error-free with short traces like a PCB.

[image]

When you activate the LED low output it means you have inverted logic output making the NAND into an AND function.